# XML time stamp "Thu, 30 Jun 2011 07:34:33 +0000" to Unixtime?

Tags: php, xml, time, rss

I have "Thu, 30 Jun 2011 07:34:33 +0000" as a time stamp from Twitter RSS feed. My server is in Eastern time. I need to some how convert this over to unixtime. I have no clue where to start. I guess Twitter would be in pacific time unless its like 24 hours.

I also have another rss feed that uses the same format. Any ideas? Not even sure what i would type in to Google to find a answer for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `strtotime()`;

e.g.: `strtotime("Thu, 30 Jun 2011 07:34:33 +0000")`

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Glad it was that simple. I was thinking it was going to be a lot of math and messy code to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `strtotime()` function:

```
 date_default_timezone_set($user_timezone); // Set the user's timezone if you'd like

 $time = strtotime("Thu, 30 Jun 2011 07:34:33 +0000") // Convert the time

 echo date("l M j \- g:ia", $time); // Print it in any format you want!
```

And for future reference, try "php twitter date unix" on Google for next time :)